# Web programming download and run file on client with client's permission

Tags: javascript, java, windows, web, client

Just a big disclaimer, this is not malware related, I want the user to be required to check a box and click a button, or something along those lines.

I'm creating a website for an application that I've made, and I generate a unique build of the application for each customer, every time they want to use the application.

This means they have to download it each and every time they want to use it. The application is just for windows.

What I would like to happen is:

1. User clicks run button.
2. User says "Yes, I would like to run it".
3. File is downloaded onto the users machine.
4. File is executed.

I know that Java applets are capable of doing this, but they're not used anymore and also require java (yes they are also blocked by default, but again, that's not the issue).

Are there any alternatives to Java applets?

Best regards

Comment: Alternatives to what? You have to send your executable to the client, because you have them downloading it each time. So what other alternatives could there be? You have the executable at location A, and you need it to run at location B. one way or another, that location B has to get a copy of the exe to run it.

Comment: Didn't think it was hard too understand what I'm looking for, but again I wrote the question. I have edited the question to include what I'm looking for alternatives to. I just need something that is somewhat along the lines of what I would like to happen.

Comment: Doesn't make sense they have to download each time they want to use it. Doesn't sound very user friendly

Comment: The browser can't run local files. If you want to create the application using web technologies, have you considered using [Electron?](http://electron.atom.io/) It will give you access to the file system.

Comment: I realize it's not user friendly, but sadly it's a precaution I have to take.

Comment: @MikeC My application reads another processes memory, and it seems like Electron with help from a library might actually be able to do this as well. A problem that could arise is the speed at which it reads the memory, as it has to talk to .NET before talking to the Windows API. I'll give it a try if I can find anything else. Thanks!

Comment: @Helios No worries :) Extra pro-tip: if you want to do interop between JS and C# then you may want to look into [Edge.js](http://tjanczuk.github.io/edge/#/) if you haven't already. Anyway, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Unless you use ActiveX (and restrict the users to using Internet Explorer), this cannot be achieved without browser plug-in support.
With ActiveX you can pretty much do anything (even run commands from the command prompt on the client's machine). Of course, for that to happen, you need the user's permission beforehand.

EDIT: As commented below, Microsoft is phasing out ActiveX support. So, as of now, what you're trying to achieve needs magic.

Comment: It's also being [phased out entirely by Microsoft](http://www.computerworld.com/article/2920892/web-browsers/microsoft-nixes-activex-add-on-technology-in-new-edge-browser.html). Older versions of IE still support it.